# Cannot parse attribute in XML file using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to parse an XML file, using a method that I copied from elsewhere and works fine with XML that has only elements with no attributes, but fails with attributes. Sample XML look like this:

```
<name>tester</name>
<trkseg>
  <trkpt lat="50.26241" lon="-5.05005">
    <ele>6.9</ele>
  </trkpt>
  <trkpt lat="50.26242" lon="-5.05012">
    <ele>6.9</ele>
  </trkpt>
  ....
```

and my code snippet looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<Track> tracks =
    from trackElement in root.Descendants(ns1 + "trkseg")
    select new Track
    {
        TrackPoints =
            (from trackPointElement in trackElement.Descendants(ns1 + "trkpt")
             select new TrackPoint
             {
                 pos = new Position
                 {
                     LatitudeDegrees = Convert.ToDouble(trackPointElement.Attribute(ns1 + "lat").Value),
                     LongitudeDegrees = Convert.ToDouble(trackPointElement.Attribute(ns1 + "lon").Value),

                 },
                 AltitudeMeters = trackPointElement.Element(ns1 + "ele") != null
                                 ? Convert.ToDouble(trackPointElement.Element(ns1 + "ele").Value) : 0.0,
             }).ToList()
    };
```

but I am getting a null exception on the attribute ("System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Attribute(...) returned null"). The 'ele' element, and the 'name' element are correctly found (if I just create a dummy position of (0,0) instead, the whole file parses correctly).
How should I code the attribute value?

Comment: Unlike elements, attributes are never in a namespace by default, so replace `trackPointElement.Attribute(ns1 + "lat")` with `trackPointElement.Attribute("lat")`, and similarly for `"lon"`.

Comment: Also you can do `(double)trackPointElement.Attribute("lat")` instead of using `Convert.ToDouble`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike elements, XML attributes are never in a namespace by default, so replace `trackPointElement.Attribute(ns1 + "lat")` with `trackPointElement.Attribute("lat")`:

```
pos = new Position
{
    LatitudeDegrees = XmlConvert.ToDouble(trackPointElement.Attribute("lat").Value),
    LongitudeDegrees = XmlConvert.ToDouble(trackPointElement.Attribute("lon").Value),
}
```

For confirmation see [Namespaces in XML 1.0 (Third Edition): 6.2 Namespace Defaulting](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting):

> The namespace name for an unprefixed attribute name always has no value.

I also recommend replacing `Convert.ToDouble()` with [`XmlConvert.ToDouble()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.todouble?view=net-5.0) to ensure that the XML is parsed consistently across locales.  Or use the [explicit conversion to `double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xattribute.op_explicit?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_Linq_XAttribute_op_Explicit_System_Xml_Linq_XAttribute__System_Double) as mentioned in comments by [juharr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302918/juharr) which does the same thing.